# How to reflect changes made to original LXC container on overlayFS snapshots?

Tags: apt, lxc, overlayfs

In order to make updates easier and limit there size, I created a base LXC container, let's say c1, where i installed and configure a few default packages (using apt) which are common to all my containers.

I then created several snapshots of the c1 container backed by overlayfs on which i installed my applications (also using apt).

My setup is aimed to be similar to [this post](https://www.hastexo.com/blogs/florian/2016/02/21/containers-just-because-everyone-else/), except i use a container instead of host

However, now when i update c1, changes are not reflected on snapshots, even after either container restart or system reboot.

So my question is what did i misunderstood/did wrong ?